# How to change temporary variable color in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, color-scheme

On PyCharm, the color for temporary variables are red. Is it possible to change the color for these variables? I am using PyCharm Professional 2020.1.2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
`Settings` > `Editor` > `Color Scheme` > `Python` > `Keyword Argument` > `Foreground`

Answer (score 1):

Open up **File** > **Settings** > **Editor** > **Color Scheme** > **Python** and then change the color of "Keyword argument":

[image: settings screenshot]